# how to disable exists content in a textbox in jquery html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created one **multi line text box**.In that text box every time some **remarks** should be added with the different users. But existing content would not change or delete. The new text should add with that text box.

I tried the many ways to do this. But i can't find any one idea. People please help me to fix this issue.

```
<%: Html.TextArea("Remark", Model.Remarks, new { @maxlength = "400" })%>
```

Comment: pls see edited answer - with read-only and line breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example. Its better to have an input below the text area to get the text from to append and then clear it once appended, but you get the gist. It requires jquery.

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        valAppend: function(text){
            return this.each(function(i,e){
                var $i =$('#remark')
                var $e = $('#comment');
                $i.val($i.val()  +'\n'  + $e.val());
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);


$('#append').click(function(){
    $('textarea').valAppend();
    $('#comment').val('');
    $('textarea').attr('readonly','readonly');
});
```

```css
textarea, input{display:block;}
#remark{height:100px; width:200px;border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="remark"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="comment" placeholder ="enter commment"></input>
<input type="button" id="append" value="append" />
```

Comment: But existing content should show. but it should be hidden. not editable. they can add new content. while saving data all those things will be add.

Comment: ah i missed that .. i'll have another fiddle